# Assigning Edit rights to the Project Manager of a project - OpenERP Access Rights

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm trying to make the "Edit" button on the Project form to only be visible if the user logged into the system is the Project Manager of that project. I've been reading various answers online regarding this, gathering some understanding of Access Rights vs. Record Rules but I haven't been able to get this working. To my understanding, Access Rights over-ride Record Rules. So, if I create a record rule under the group "Project/User" that has read and write access with the domain as the following:

`[('user_id','=',user.id)]`

This will be over-ridden by the Access Rights for Project/User anyway? So How would I get this to work?
Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Record Rules can override Access Rights.
Here is an example where record rules are used to change the `base_user` edit capabilities depending on the Task `state`: https://github.com/OCA/project-service/tree/8.0/project_baseuser/security

However, the "edit" button is not dynamically visible depending on the Task Status: it's always visible but the rules may or may not allow to write upon "Save".

Comment: Hi Daniel, It doesn't work in odoo v11 even though I corrected all the fields. Do you have any update version of those settings for v11? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Access Control List is checked before Record Rules.

Because Access Control List is a CRUD security on models (create/read/update/delete).

Only if ACL is passed next record level security comes in.

As far as I understood you want to give Project User permission to edit his own projects (he is in group Project User not Project Manager but set as Project Manager for exact Project by Project Manager group user LOL).

I did this by doing the following:

1) Give project users Project Manager role.

2) Restrict them to only modify own projects by creating a Global rule (no group is set) with the following domain on update / delete operations:

```
['|', ('user_id','=',user.id),('create_uid','=',user.id)]
```

P,S, Here is screenshot - http://awesomescreenshot.com/0083nqyf76

Comment: This domain allows to edit / delete projects only to project creators and to users set as project manager.

Answer (score 0):

For the model project.project, provide the write permission only to the group project manager.Go to settings/techical/security. There you can see the access control list. CHeck what all group is provided to the project.project model.for every group other than project manager, remove the write permission